# Как объективно сравнить pe-файл и его проекцию в памяти?

Tags: winapi, c++, ассемблер

Суть такова: мы получаем информацию о процессе, получаем его базовый адрес и путь к файлу. Затем мне нужно проанализировать память и файл и понять, загружено ли в память именно это приложение или же его проекцию заменили на другое приложение. Первоначальная идея была: брать контрольную сумму от секции кода, но, как выяснилось, почему-то результирующие хэши получаются разные. [Причём, например, в ходе отладки выяснил, первые 100/1000 байт совпадают, а дальше пошли различия.] Так вот, есть ли ещё идеи, как можно понять, загружено ли целевое приложение, или же его заменили? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Во времена managed-приложений и crl/jit? Серьезно?

Comment: @Макс Мазурин, думаю надо считать хэши памяти  и файла *без учета адресов*, на которые есть ссылки из [Relocation Table](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&noj=1&hl=ru&biw=1131&bih=786&q=relocation+table+pe&oq=Relocation+Table&gs_l=serp.1.1.0l2j0i22i30l7j0i22i10i30.3028515.3028515.0.3031776.1.1.0.0.0.0.115.115.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.53.serp..0.1.114.1HEWjoaFhKo) (и м.б. каких-то еще секций pe-файла).

Подробнее можете посмотреть, например, [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) или  [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

Comment: К вышесказанному хочу добавить что стоит сравнивать только MZPE-заголовок и read-only секции с правами на исполнение. Т.е. только секции с кодом, т.к. данные в процессе выполнения могут меняться.

Comment: @Veliant, в общем случае секция кода тоже может иметь флаг "изменяемая", а секция данных - наоборот, read-only.
По поводу перемещаемых элементов - при расчете хешей лучше не игнорировать абсолютные адреса, а подставлять вместо них относительные, т.к. различия могут затрагивать именно их.